# How to understand Haskell typeclass definitions with "| m -> s" and the like

Tags: haskell

I can't seem to find books really explaining what the `| m -> s` means in the `MonadState` type class definition:

```hs
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
  {- other stuff here -}
```

The book I'm currently reading explains

> The `s` type variable represents a type of state. It is uniquely determined by the monad `m` as specified by the `| m -> s` part.

but I don't understand what that exactly means.

The extent to which I understand is that `m` has to be some type with a `Monad` instance, and `m` will have a value that it contains. Does it mean that `s` is what would appear as `m s` if the provided monad were to show up in a type expression--i.e. something like `return :: Monad m => s -> m s`?

Comment: The GHC documentation has a chapter on [Functional dependencies](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/functional_dependencies.html).

Comment: It means `s` is the one -- and only -- type of the state stored in the monad `m` (at least, the only state accessible via the `MonadState` typeclass).

Comment: In practical terms this means `(MonadState YourState m, MonadState s m)` can be simplified to just `MonadState YourState m` because for each `m` there’s a unique `s`. Without the fundep, the relation `MonadState` would be just a set of pairs of types (s, m) with no constraints between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [**functional dependency**](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/functional_dependencies.html). All it does is put some restrictions on the instances you're allowed to define for that class.

It means the variables to the left of the arrow (`m` in this case) must *determine* the ones to the right of the arrow (`s` in this case).<sup>1</sup> You are not allowed to define multiple instances such that you are unable to tell what `s` should be immediately upon making a choice for `m`.

For example, this is illegal:

```
data MyStateMonad a = ...

instance MonadState Int MyStateMonad

instance MonadState Bool MyStateMonad
```

With the above instances, once `m` is determined to be `MyStateMonad` we can't immediately deduce what `s` must be; there are instances for both `Int` and `Bool`. That would be perfectly fine in a normal multi-parameter type class, but the functional dependency `m -> s` forbids it.

The main thing it *achieves* (why the authors wanted to impose that restriction) is that GHC is aware of the restriction, and can use it during type inference. It would be very common to have a function that takes a monadic value with a `MonadState` constraint (`m a` for some `a`), but only interacts with the `s` state type internally. If GHC had to consider the possibility that there could be many `MonadState` instances for each `m`, with varying `s`, then code like this would frequently be ambiguous; the programmer would have to add in more type annotations to get it to compile.

But that's usually not a possible situation anyway, since a lot of `MonadState` instances are ultimately built on `StateT`<sup>2</sup>, which looks like this:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

This *already* has a type parameter for the state! We're almost never going to want a type `M` with a `StateT Int _ _` inside it to have a `MonadState Bool M` instance; we've already determined that the state should be `Int` by one of the parameters to the `StateT` we use. The only way it could really make sense is if `M` had *both* a `StateT Int _ _` inside it *and* a `StateT Bool _ _`; theoretically we could then have wanted two `MonadState` instances for `M` with the types controlling which one is used.<sup>3</sup>

But instead the authors decided to use a functional dependency to sacrifice the ability to write such things, and instead better support the use case where there is only a single state type that makes sense for any given state monad. Now as soon as your type signatures have pinned down the monad you're using, the compiler can use this to identify the `MonadState` instance which then tells it what `s` must be. This effectively adds type information to every use of `MonadState` methods without requiring the programmer to write additional type annotations.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or phrased the other way around, the ones to the right of the arrow *depend upon* the ones on the left - in exactly the same way that a function's result depends upon its arguments (hence the term functional dependency).

---

<sup>2</sup> By "ultimately built on" I don't necessarily mean that the `MonadState` instance is literally for some combination of `StateT`'s parameters. Just that somewhere inside the first parameter of the instance will often be a `StateT`, with `MonadState` instances lifting the "state" behaviour out to the top.

---

<sup>3</sup> I'm not actually sure whether you could even get that to pass the monad laws.